# Pulling large amounts of data from JSON to iOS; how can I speed up the load time?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json

I'm using PHP files to output JSON data from a MySQL database. The database contains over 12,000 rows, and I'm pulling all of this data to an iOS TableView (it's a customer list). Is there a way to make the load time any faster? Right now, it takes a good 10 seconds for the app to load the data. I'm using the below code to retrieve the information:

```
       - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URLHERE.php"];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
        {
            data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
        {
            [data appendData:theData];

        }

        - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            Customers = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
            [CustomerTableView reloadData];

        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
        {
            UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure that you're connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorView show];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


        }
        - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

        {
            return 1;

        }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CustomerTableIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";

        CustomerCell *cell = (CustomerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomerTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomerCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

            NSLog(@"Using the search results");

            cell.customerfname.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerfname"];

            cell.customerlname.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerlname"];

            cell.customeremail.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customeremail"];

            cell.lastupdate.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lastupdate"];

            cell.customerphone.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerphone"];


            NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);



        } else {
            NSLog(@"Using the Full List!");

            cell.customerfname.text = [[Customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerfname"];

            cell.customerlname.text = [[Customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerlname"];

            cell.customeremail.text = [[Customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customeremail"];

            cell.lastupdate.text = [[Customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lastupdate"];

            cell.customerphone.text = [[Customers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"customerphone"];


        }

        return cell;

    }
}
```

Comment: Load time for this can be affected by any number of including things from connection speed to database performance. Are your database tables indexed properly? Are you using EXPLAIN to see how your query is being run and what indexes are being used? How long does it take to run the queries from the desktop? Are you attempting this from various locations over various connection types (wifi, 4g, LTE, etc.)?

Comment: What part is slow? Use Instruments (part of Xcode) to find out where the problem is. If you can't see the problem, you can't fix the problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've tried it on various connections; slow on all.

Comment: @Zaph Problem? I thought it was just loading slower because I have so much data being pulled?

Comment: Could be, might be something else. Have you measured the connection time? Personally I would be in Charles Proxy already to see if it was a connection time issue. I have seen really slow performance because of logging. You need to find the times for the various components.

Comment: Just looking at the path: 1. DB query to php. 2. php conversion to JSON. 3. connection to move the data. 4. deserialization in iOS. 5. Table display time. And many of these can be broken down further. The big question, do you need to get *all* the data initially or is there  some subset that can be used to parially populate the table to make it seem faster to the use and then request the rest.

Comment: @Zaph I'm open to suggestions :) I need the data at all once, but how could I go about loading fewer results and still be able to obtain more? E.g. Can the table load 100 results, and only load more when a user scrolls down and pushes a "see more..." button?

Comment: The table does not really contain the data, the data comes from the datasource and the datasource can be updated. You can also deserialize the JSON at it is received with the partial flag.  But you really need to find out what is slow. Story: I was once hired by a large company based on the answer to one question: "What would you do if a section of code was slow". My answer was "I would first profile..." and I was cut off, that is all they wanted to hear. Use Instruments, add timing calculations in the server and iOS. Until you know where the problem is it is all guesswork—mostly wrong.